# Flutter - Can't open Sembast database in testWidgets test

Tags: database, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm currently using the `Sembast` database library and want to write a component test. If I try to open a `Sembast` database in a `testWidgets` test, it hangs indefinitely:

```
  testWidgets('database', () async {
    await databaseFactoryIo.openDatabase('database');
    expect(1, 1); //never reaches this line
  });
```

However, everything works fine when in a `test` test:

```
  test('database', () async {
    await databaseFactoryIo.openDatabase('database');
    expect(1, 1); //passes
  });
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think file system access is possible in write mode during testWidgets without changes (try to create a directory, it won't work neither).

What you could do during unittest is to use a different factory: `databaseFactoryMemory`

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:sembast/sembast_memory.dart';

Future main() async {
  testWidgets('database', (tester) async {
    var db = await databaseFactoryMemory.openDatabase('database');
    expect(db, isNotNull);
    await db.close();
  });
}
```